# Generate DDL SQL create table statement after scanning CSV file

Tags: sql, csv, ddl, delimited

Are there any command line tools (Linux, Mac, and/or Windows) that I could use to scan a delimited file and output a DDL create table statement with the data type determined for me?

Did some googling, but couldn't find anything.  Was wondering if others might know, thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[DDL-generator](https://github.com/catherinedevlin/ddl-generator) can do this. It can generate DDL's for YAML, JSON, CSV, Pickle and HTML (although I don't know how the last one works). I just tried it on some data exported from Salesforce and it worked pretty well. Note you need to use it with Python 3, I could not get it to work with Python 2.7.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try https://github.com/mshanu/idli. It can take csv file as input and can generate create statement with appropriate types.It can generate for mysql, oracle and postgres. I am actively working on this and happy to receive feedback for future improvement

Comment: Would it be better to put in more explanation?

Answer (score 0):

Recently I tried this online tool [convertcsv.com/csv-to-sql](https://www.convertcsv.com/csv-to-sql.htm). I did some adjustments but it helped me a lot!